# Run ElasticSearch on a Raspberry Pi: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine

Tags: elasticsearch, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I'm trying to run ElasticSearch on a Raspberry Pi 3B with Raspbian (Buster). I followed the guide at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/deb.html.

I can start/stop the service, but I can't seem to connect to the HTTP endpoint (eg. rpi-ip-address:9200) nor `curl 127.0.0.1:9200`. It just says:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 9200: Connection refused
```

These are the Java versions on my Raspberry Pi:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ java -version
openjdk version "11.0.5" 2019-10-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.5+10-post-Raspbian-1deb10u1)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 11.0.5+10-post-Raspbian-1deb10u1, mixed mode)
```

Linux information:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ uname -r
4.19.88-v7+
```

You can get more information about what's going wrong when running the service binary directly:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo service elasticsearch stop
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo service elasticsearch status
● elasticsearch.service - LSB: Starts elasticsearch
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/elasticsearch; generated)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Sun 2019-12-15 14:43:16 GMT; 2min 19s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 8654 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/elasticsearch start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 18073 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/elasticsearch stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Dec 15 11:53:21 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Starts elasticsearch...
Dec 15 11:53:21 raspberrypi elasticsearch[8654]: [warning] /etc/init.d/elasticsearch: JVM flavor 'sun6' not understood
Dec 15 11:53:21 raspberrypi elasticsearch[8654]: Starting Elasticsearch Server:.
Dec 15 11:53:21 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started LSB: Starts elasticsearch.
Dec 15 14:43:16 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: Starts elasticsearch...
Dec 15 14:43:16 raspberrypi elasticsearch[18073]: [warning] /etc/init.d/elasticsearch: JVM flavor 'sun6' not understood
Dec 15 14:43:16 raspberrypi elasticsearch[18073]: Stopping Elasticsearch Server: Elasticsearch Server is not running but pid file exists, cleaning up.
Dec 15 14:43:16 raspberrypi systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Succeeded.
Dec 15 14:43:16 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: Starts elasticsearch.
```

And then:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch
Unrecognized VM option 'UseParNewGC'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

I already checked other threads but couldn't find a solution.

More things to check:

- **/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml:** Inserted `network.bind_host: 0.0.0.0`
- **/etc/default/elasticsearch:**

  - Uncommented **START_DAEMON=true**
  - Added **JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-armhf** (this folder actually exists)
  - Uncommented and modified: **ES_HEAP_SIZE=256m**
- There are no logs written to **/var/log/elasticsearch/**

And when afterwards I start ES again:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo service elasticsearch start
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo service elasticsearch status
● elasticsearch.service - LSB: Starts elasticsearch
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/elasticsearch; generated)
   Active: active (exited) since Sun 2019-12-15 14:57:29 GMT; 3s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 18846 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/elasticsearch start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Dec 15 14:57:29 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Starts elasticsearch...
Dec 15 14:57:29 raspberrypi elasticsearch[18846]: [warning] /etc/init.d/elasticsearch: JVM flavor 'sun6' not understood
Dec 15 14:57:29 raspberrypi elasticsearch[18846]: Starting Elasticsearch Server:.
Dec 15 14:57:29 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started LSB: Starts elasticsearch.
```

And these are the openjdk runtimes (**/usr/lib/java-wrappers/jvm-list.sh**):

```
...

# Now, free runtimes:
__jvm_openjdk6="/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-$__arch /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk"
__jvm_openjdk7="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-$__arch /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk"
__jvm_openjdk8="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-$__arch /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk"
__jvm_openjdk9="/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-$__arch /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk"
__jvm_openjdk10="/usr/lib/jvm/java-10-openjdk-$__arch /usr/lib/jvm/java-10-openjdk"
__jvm_openjdk11="/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-$__arch /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk"
```

Why can't the Java Virtual machine be started?

Answer (score 0):

openjdk version "11.0.5" could be an issue. Install JDK 8 and set path.

The heap size could be an issue as well. I believe the RasberrypPI 3B has only 1 GB of memory. Allocate as much as possible.

Check your firewall configuration as well if you want to access it remotely.

Comment: I'll take a look at this tonight at home. One thing I also tried (on a previous image) was modifying **/etc/elasticsearch/jvm.options** setting to -Xms512M and -Xmx512M.

Answer (score 0):

Been facing this problem today also.

Here are some findings.

The problem with not being able to create a virtual machine was due to a folder permission problem. The inability to create a log file caused the java virtual machine to fail. Had to change owner and modes like so.

```
sudo chown root:root /var/lib/elasticsearch
sudo chown root:root /var/log/elasticsearch

sudo chmod 777 /var/lib/elasticsearch
sudo chmod 777 /var/log/elasticsearch
```

Also installed OpenJdk 8

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

This caused elasticsearch to still fail but without any exceptions.

```
service elasticsearch status
```

Returned

```
● elasticsearch.service - Elasticsearch
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Sun 2020-09-06 18:48:39 UTC; 6min ago
       Docs: https://www.elastic.co
    Process: 7501 ExecStart=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/systemd-entrypoint -p ${PID_DIR}/elasticsearch.pid --quiet (code=exited, status=143)
   Main PID: 7501 (code=exited, status=143)

Sep 06 18:47:07 es systemd[1]: Starting Elasticsearch...
Sep 06 18:48:37 es systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: start operation timed out. Terminating.
Sep 06 18:48:39 es systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Sep 06 18:48:39 es systemd[1]: Failed to start Elasticsearch.
```

While...

```
journalctl -xe
```

Returned no error information about the service at all. The Java VM was being created successfully.

The main elasticsearch log shows nothing being a problem.

Still doesn't run.